# How to embed Ruby code in Rails i18n yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I want to create a sentence that can be singular or plural based on the `count` parameter:

```
# When count is 1
"This profile still contains 1 post"

# When count is 2
"This profile still contains 2 posts"
```

Using Rails i18n mechanism, I believe I have to embed Ruby code to get the correct pluralization for the word "post". I'm trying to build it like this, but it's not working:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  message: "This profile still contains %{count} <%= Post.model_name.human(count: count).lowercase %>"

# Output of I18n.translate(:message, count: 2)
"This profile still contains 2 <%= Post.model_name.human(count: count).lowercase %>"
```

I already tried `<%= %>`, `%{ }`, `#{ }` and `{{ }}` and all failed.

Is it even possible to embed Ruby code in i18n file? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization), you should do something like this:

```
en:
  message:
    one: This profile still contains 1 post
    other: This profile still contains %{count} posts
```

And call it:

```
I18n.t('message', count: count)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: First of all, What is the output of this: `Post.model_name.human(count: count).lowercase`? I expected it to be a numer?

Comment: The output of that is the name of the model, in singular or plural, depending on the value of `count`. Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveModel/Name/human

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's easier to use and to understand, despite the repetition of some words. But both answers are good and valid. Thank you and @sovalina.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pluralize` method :

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  message: "This profile still contains"
```

view

```
"#{I18n.t('message')} #{Post.count} #{Post.model_name.human.pluralize(Post.count).downcase}."

#=> output : "This profile still contains 1 post." or "This profile still contains XX posts"
```

It works but i recommend you to put all the view logic in a helper.

**Note** : i use global `Post.count` for the example but you can use any count you want as `user.posts.count` etc...

Comment: Using `pluralize` like this only works in English. In other languages, it simply appends an "s" to the word, which is not always correct. But the solution would be correct if put like this: `"#{I18n.t('message')} #{Post.count} #{Post.model_name.human(count: Post.count).downcase}."`. Assuming the yml file contains the translations of the model name, including `one:` and `other:`.